# How to kill all processes started by dotnet run?

Tags: python, linux, .net-core, process

I am having a strange issue with killing processes started by `dotnet run`

I start the application using using python like this:

```
processObj = subprocess.Popen(['dotnet', 'run', '-p', filePath])
```

I got these new processes:

```
PID
 18    dotnet run -p /.../xxxx.csproj
 56    /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet exec /.../VBCSCompiler.dll
 75    /.../my-service-name
```

I kill them one by using python like this.

```
os.kill(18), signal.SIGKILL)
os.kill(56), signal.SIGKILL)
os.kill(75), signal.SIGKILL)
```

However, only process 18 is killed. Really not sure what's going on, because process both 10 and 56 are child of process 1 (the robot I used to call python script), but, it only kills 18 and not 56. And 75 is child of process 18, which is not killed as well.

How do I kill process 56 and 75?

Thank you

Update:
The solution is to replace all my code with `\\` to `/`. Like there are configs using paths in windows format, and I changed them to linux format, and it becomes ok. Interestingly it doesn't just crash with bad input, instead of hang like the comments suggested.

Comment: The only case in which SIGKILL would be ignored is if the processes are in a "D" state (paused waiting on I/O). Processes can't ignore SIGKILL, so only in the case in which the kernel can't send the signal is it not applied.

Comment: You can't kill a process stuck on pending I/O, but that should only happen if there is a hardware issue such as a disk or NFS volume going away.

Comment: @jordanm thank you, do you know why they are in D state? Like VBCSCompiler.dll, why was it in D sate?

Comment: @jordanm not sure how I can solve the problem, it is just running on docker on Linux host and Linux container. But, at least I get a better idea, thank you.

Comment: generally either a) kernel bugs (unlikely) or b) a mount point disappearing

Comment: okie, I will try looking for those, thank you for the help @jordanm

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command.

```
pkill -f dotnet
```